# Получение generic-типа

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть нижеприведённый код. Код пытается сделать класс для создания обработчиков React-компонента

```
import * as React    from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react'

type PropTypes = {
    str: string
}

// Класс компонента
class MyComponent extends Component<PropTypes> {
    handlers: Handlers

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handlers = new Handlers(this)
    }

    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handlers.onClick}/>
    }
}

// Абстрактный класс для создания классов с обработчиками
abstract class HandlersCreator<C extends Component> {
    props: Pick<C, 'props'> // Пытаемся присвоить тип «props». 
    // Как-то нужно здесь использовать PropTypes, полученный из «C»

    constructor(public component: Readonly<C>) {
        // Тут происходит ругань, что нельзя присвоить, ибо типы 
        // 'C["props"]' и 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<{}>'
        // несовместимы
        this.props = component.props
    }
}

// Класс с обработчиками
class Handlers extends HandlersCreator<MyComponent> {
    constructor(component: MyComponent) {
        super(component)

        // Тут тоже ошибка
        // Property 'str' does not exist on type 'Pick<MyComponent, "props">'
        console.log(this.props.str)
    }

    public onClick() {
        // Тут колдунство для клика
    }
}
```

Требуется в HandlerCreator'е получить тип свойства «props» реакт-компонента. 
Я полагаю, его нужно как-то получить из generic'а C. Напрямую использовать PropTypes нельзя. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного проще, чем я думал:

```
interface HandlersCreator<C extends Component> {
    props: C['props']
}
```